Matplotlib Gridspec with aspect ratio
I am trying to do a Gridspec with this layout:
Layout looking as it is supposed to
The lower left plot is supposed to be of equal aspect ratio. Sadly, I had to adjust the window size to get this picture. For other sizes, either the top or right plots don't align with the bottom left plot.
Layout with plots that are not aligned
My code looks like this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3, width_ratios=[1, 1/4, 1/32], height_ratios=[1/32, 1/4, 1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[2, 0])
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax_histx = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex=ax)
ax_histy = plt.subplot(gs[2, 1], sharey=ax)

cax = plt.subplot(gs[2, 2])
cax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])

plt.show()

The subplots align perfectly, if I don't set the aspect ratio. But it seems, that I can't have both aligning and my equal aspect ratio.
Also, the bottom left figure isn't always supposed to be a square. For example, if I set different limits for x and y
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)

it should be a rectangle with width=2*height, so that all cells in the plot are squares.
Square with wrong alignment

Your code produces a correct looking plot for me with ax.set_aspect('equal') included. What version of matplotlib are you using? I used version 3.8.2.

Actually, I see that if I plot stuff in ax then that axis does become misaligned.

Are you happy to manually set the limits in the axis? If so, so long as you keep your figsize set such that you have a square figure, you can remove ax.set_aspect('equal') and just have, e.g., ax.set_xlim([0, 1]) and ax.set_ylim([0, 1]).

I tried that, but that doesn't fix the aspect ratio.

You could consider using the inset_axes method for laying out the axes, instead of GridSpec.  Here I have hard-coded positions for each inset axes, but you might want to make them a function of your main axes' limits.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8), layout='compressed')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax_histx = ax.inset_axes([0, 1.2, 1, 0.25], sharex=ax)
ax_histy = ax.inset_axes([1.1, 0, 0.25, 1], sharey=ax)

cax = ax.inset_axes([0, 1.65, 1, 0.125])
cax2 = ax.inset_axes([1.45, 0, 0.125, 1])

ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)

plt.show()



Thanks, that seems to be working. That has nothing to do with the original question, but do you know, if I can align the labels for the axes? fig.align_labels() doesn't seem to do anything with this approach.

@RaphBilder perhaps better to open a new question about aligning labels.  ax.align_labels will not work with inset axes.

Setting the axis aspect will resize the axis, but not the figure.
I can't see any other way than setting the figure size adequately, with some math.
In your case it is thankfully quite easy, since any squared figure size will do the job.
Actually it is not the figure size that matters, but the extent of the rectangle containing all the subplots inside the figure.
The catch is that the default margins between the figure extent and the subplots extent make the subplots extent not square when the figure size is.
(This is figure.subplot.left/right/bottom/top set to 0.125/0.9/0.11/0.88 in the default rcParams).
To sum up, put a squared figure size, and fix the left/right/bottom/top args of the GridSpec and you're good to go:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(
    nrows=3,
    ncols=3,
    width_ratios=[1, 1 / 4, 1 / 32],
    height_ratios=[1 / 32, 1 / 4, 1],
    bottom=0.1,
    top=0.9,
    left=0.1,
    right=0.9,
    # wspace=0,
    # hspace=0,
)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[2, 0])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

ax_histx = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0], sharex=ax)
ax_histy = plt.subplot(gs[2, 1], sharey=ax)

cax = plt.subplot(gs[2, 2])
cax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])

plt.show()



Thanks for the great answer. Sadly, I can't figure out, how to do that, if the bottom left plot is no square but a rectangle (see edit in the original question). Do you have any ideas for that?

Also, if I move the window borders, it still misalignes. But that's a secondary thought, as the plot saves perfectly aligned to file.

Yes it is more difficult when that is not a square. Basically you need to compute the aspect ratio of the subplot extent yourself. And it should take the wspace into account. The way of the other answer with inset_axes seems to fit the job more, with still some tweaks to add for the figure size I think.
